# Need Better Solution to remove special characters and Numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there any better way to remove all the special characters and numbers in a column, not limited to one or two almost to remove all the special characters and numbers.
As of now I I am using this query (Jst Logic part). Let me know is there any better choice as my table contains minimum 5 million records

```
Declare @name varchar(1000) = '231323Lig%$%$h$%t'
Declare @dumy varchar(1000)

while(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@name)<>0)
    SET @name   = stuff(@name,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',@name),1,'')


while(PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',@name)<>0)
begin
    SET @dumy = isnull(@dumy,'')+substring(@name,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',@name),1)
    SET @name = stuff(@name,PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%',@name),1,'')
end

Set @name = @dumy

Select @name 'Clean'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this function:

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

> Call it like this:

```
Select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters('231323Lig%$%$h$%t')
```

**Output:**

---

```
Clean
Light
```

**Update**

If you want to do it for entire  table just try like this

```
Select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters(ColumnName),OtherColumn1,OtherColumn2 
FROM Table1
```

Comment: Thanks it is gud, since it is a table I cannot pass all the records to a function can  u provide me a solution to do it for the entire table atonce.

Comment: @user3751754- Yes You can do it for entire table. See my updated answer. Mark answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your function to one WHILE loop:

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(MAX) = '231323Lig%$%$h$%t'
DECLARE @Expression NVARCHAR(32) = '%[^A-Z]%'

WHILE PATINDEX(@Expression, @String) > 0
    SET @String = STUFF(@String, PATINDEX(@Expression, @String), 1, '')

RETURN @String
```

A `CLR` function could be faster than the pure T-SQL implementation.

```
Regex.Replace(str, "[^a-zA-Z]+", "", RegexOptions.Compiled)
```