# In string 0 to 9 number replace with blank in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have String Like

```
208Pb,
75As,
111Cd
```

I want to relapse number with blank and result 
 AS Like

```
Pb,
AS,
cd
```

Comment: Do you have strings with 2 trailing chars?

Comment: NO its not 2 char its dynamic

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar  Thnx a lot your answer is correct its work then why you delete your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305236/need-better-solution-to-remove-special-characters-and-numbers/24305488#24305488)**

**Method 1:**

> Try this function:

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNonAlphaCharacters](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin

    Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
    Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z]%'
    While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
        Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

    Return @Temp
End
```

> Call it like this:

```
Select dbo.RemoveNonAlphaCharacters('208Pb')
```

**Output:**

---

```
Pb
```

**Method 2:**

```
    DECLARE @str VARCHAR(400)
    DECLARE @expres  VARCHAR(50) = '%[0-9]%'
    SET @str = '208Pb'
    WHILE PATINDEX( @expres, @str ) > 0
      SET @str = Replace(REPLACE( @str, SUBSTRING( @str, PATINDEX( @expres, @str ), 1 ),''),'-',' ')

    SELECT @str
```

**Output:**

---

```
Pb
```

Comment: You have enough rep to vote to close as dupe rather than copy another answer.

Comment: It's up to you if you want to delete it. But IMO you firstly should have considered crediting [the original author](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008566/73226) of the `RemoveNonAlphaCharacters` function. Then you should have considered whether the fact that the answer was already found on SO probably makes the question a dupe.