# Trying to make a column for full addresses from several other columns, but having trouble with some addresses

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset with housing numbers, street addresses, and zip codes. I am trying to create another column which will include the housing numbers and street addresses. I'm working with about 100,000 datapoints. Most of my addresses are fine, but it appears that TELEGRAPH St has unit numbers at the end, which I do not want. Is there a way I can ask SQL to remove the numbers at the end of all street addresses, ONLY ON TELEGRAPH ST? For instance, most streets are like "Main Street" or "Broadway" but Telegraph has "Telegraph st 400", but I want it just be Telegraph st.  I've given part of my code below, but it doesn't seem to work:

Address_Line1=CASE WHEN street1 LIKE 'TELEGRAPH%' THEN (loadd1 + ' ' + REPLACE(street1, '[0-9]', ''))
WHEN street1 LIKE 'M %[0-9]%' OR street1 like 'US %[0-9]%' THEN (loadd1 + ' ' +
CONCAT(street1, ' HWY'))
ELSE loadd1+ ' ' +street1 END

The second portion of my code "WHEN street1 like 'M %[0-9]%'... works just fine, but when I check the output, TELEGRAPH ST still has the unit number at the end.

I've also attempted (very poorly) to create a function, but that didn't work either.

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].NoNumbers(@x VARCHAR(MAX))

RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)

BEGIN

```
CASE WHEN @x LIKE '%[0-9]%'THEN SUBSTRING(@x,0,CHARINDEX('%[0-9]%',@x)) ELSE @x END
```

RETURN @x

END

Thanks, your help is much appreciated!

**

**

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove numbers from string sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13240298/remove-numbers-from-string-sql-server)

Comment: I used the solution provided by @SubodhW below. Thanks, everyone, for your time! :)

Comment: @Stu Yes, I think that works as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression  `REPLACE(street1, '[0-9]', '')` can't replace numbers. You may create the below function and then use like

```
WHEN street1 LIKE 'TELEGRAPH%' THEN (loadd1 + ' ' +  dbo.RemoveNumbers(street1))
```

Function :

```
Create Function [dbo].[RemoveNumbers](@Temp VarChar(1000))
Returns VarChar(1000)
AS
Begin
Declare @RemoveValues as varchar(50)
Set @RemoveValues = '%[0-9]%'
While PatIndex(@RemoveValues, @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@RemoveValues, @Temp), 1, '')

Return @Temp
End
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24339959/3334470) -

Comment: @Ntsher If this answer solves your problem, the proper thing to do is mark it as such.

Comment: @SMor I wasn't aware that we had to do that. Thanks for letting me know!